# Unable to populate in the lookup section

Tags: lookup

I have created two objects owner and contractor. I have created ownercontractorassociation as junction object for the above objects. Now when I am clicking on the lookup option, and clicking on the "go" besides the search box in the lookup window, I am not getting all the existing owner or contractor records. Is there any problem? How can I populate that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see two radio check box after the lookup window is opened - "Name" and "All fields". Please select "All fields" and search accordingly. I hope you can see these radio box.

Go to Set up -> Search settings -> Look up settings -> Check Enhanced look up check box for both Owner and Contractor object.

Comment: I am not able to see any radio boxes. Is it something I need to change in the org wide defaults.

Comment: I edited my answer. Plz check.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. But still after entering text in the search box  and clicking on the go option I am able to see. But my requirement is without entering the text in the search filed if I click on the go... all the records should be displayed. Is it possible?

Comment: By default it searches only 50 records i think but u need to enter some search parameters. If u want some custom logic then better write a custom look up using apex.

Comment: However i would suggest u to do some Google over this